# Can't get rid of NullPointerException for Comparator

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I've been struggling to get rid of a NullPointerException that occurs when calling the line of code:

```
 if (priorityComparator.compare(temp.next.value, newNode.value) >= 0 )
```

The full code is:

```
 public class HeaderLinkedPriorityQueue<E> extends 
       AbstractPriorityQueue<E> implements PriorityQueue<E> {

  //Some other methods, constructors etc.

 public boolean add (E e) {

  ListNode<E> temp = highest;


  ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E>(e, null);

  if (temp.next == null){
      //first node in a list.
      temp.next = newNode;
      objectCount++;
      return true;
  }

  //if the value of the first element following the header node is greater than the newNode add to back.
  if (priorityComparator.compare(temp.next.value, newNode.value) >= 0 ) {
      temp.next.next = newNode;
      objectCount++;
  }
  else {
      //add before the first node in the list. have temp.next point to newNode and have newNode point to the old temp.next.
      newNode.next = temp.next;
      temp.next = newNode;
      objectCount++; 
  }
  return true;
 }

 //class variables.
 private ListNode<E>           highest     = new ListNode(null, null); 
 private int                   objectCount = 0;
 private Comparator<? super E> priorityComparator;
```

I don't see anything wrong with the parameters so I'm really stumped. How can I fix this?

Comment: check temp.next.value, newNode.value are null or not

Comment: I would assume that either priorityComparator is null or temp.next.value is null or newNode.value is null.  look at the variables in a debugger.  what does the actual error message say?

Comment: Prints or debugger to find out what is wrong. Anyone of: priorityComparator, temp, temp.next or newNode. Depending on the inplementation, could also be temp.next.value or newNow.value.

Comment: Could you please show the stack trace that you get?

Comment: I'm sure its not temp, temp.next, or newNode. How can I specifically check for priorityComparator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you didn't initialize your PriorityComparator.

```
private Comparator<? super E> priorityComparator;
```

should be something like

```
private Comparator<? super E> priorityComparator = new PriorityComparator();
```

Comment: @nitiger: well, then to prove that "that's not it", please show us where in your code you in fact *do* initialize this variable. :P

Comment: I've tried initializing it there but I'm not sure which constructor initializes priorityComparator.

Comment: @nitiger: then how can you justify your first comment to tanyehzheng's answer? 1+ to his answer 1- to your question for that comment. I think that his syntax may be off, that you need to create an anonymous inner Comparator class, but his concept is likely right on the money.

Comment: So, something like this?  private Comparator<? super E> priorityComparator = new Comparator<E>() { public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) { return ((String)o1).compareTo((String) o2);}};

Comment: Hmm, I think it works now still have issues adding between values such as 3 between 5 and 4 but thanks tanyehzheng.